# Retrieving tagged pictures from flickr - results aren't what I expected

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework, flickr

I'm trying to retrieve pictures from flickr using the Zend Framework. So far I'm successful in retrieving images based upon a tag however the result is far from what I expected.

Seems that retrieving every picture tagged by a city name also returns pictures that you wouldn't want to show on a travel site even though it has been tagged by the city name.

How does gogobot manage to retrieve the correct pictures for all the cities they have? I don't want to consider having to make my own library n flickr with pictures for all the cities and have them  manually tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging images is user driven - so I could take a photo of me in London and tag it 'me', and 'london'. Then when you search you are also getting this image, as the api would suggest.

To only get photos you really want, you will either have to specify what images you want to fetch, or as you say, start your own library.

Also, on http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.html check out the 'accuracy' field

Comment: Thats true - however I would like to know how sites like gogobot and trip it have actually implemented it. The idea of accumulating pictures for hundreds of thousands of cities seems mindboggling to begin with here.